# Doubt regarding the work done by macroscopic electric fields

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, work, self-energy

Suppose I have a large collection of microscopic charges, say $10^{30}$ or so, occupying some large 3d space. I want to find the work it takes to build this collection.

In an ideal world, one would use the formula $\frac{1}{2}\iiint \rho_{micro} \phi_{micro} d\tau$ (where $\rho_{micro}$ and $\phi_{micro}$ are the microscopic charge densitiy and potential respectively). This is the true work (within the framework of classical EnM)

The true work, the work calculated using **microscopic** quantities is near impossible to calculate in practice. So we are clear that we should use **macroscopic** quantities to get a good approximate picture of the work it takes.

Now, let's say I have done Lorentz averaging of all the microscopic quantities over a volume of 1000 molecules (or equivalently, a weighted averaging, using a weight function whose range is of the order of the linear dimension of the volume of these 1000 molecules, the details of this don't matter much)

Since I've done the averaging over this volume, one can say, approximately, quantities like $\rho_{macro}$ or $\phi_{macro}$ stay somewhat constant within these blobs of charge.

We also know (again, to a good approximation) that:

$$F_{blob}= Q_{blob} \vec E_{macro} $$ where $F_{blob}$ $Q_{blob}$ and $E_{macro}$ are the force experienced by the blob, charge contained in the blob and the averages out electric field(the macroscopic field) respectively. (This is the claim in Zangwill, page 40, 2012 edition, and I've also seen this in FNH Robinson's book).

So I can safely say, the **macroscopic** work it takes to bring a blob from infinity to it's prescribed point, in the presence of the rest of the blobs, is equal to $Q_{blob} \phi_{macro} $ if our reference is to be infinity. Hence, the **macroscopic** work it takes to build a system is:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \sum \rho_{macro} \Delta V \phi_{macro} $$ where $\Delta V$ is the volume of the blob.

Consider the integral: $$\frac{1}{2} \iiint_{all space} \rho_{macro} \phi_{macro} d\tau $$
I can rewrite this as $$\sum_{all blobs} \frac{1}{2} \iiint_{each blob} \rho_{macro} \phi_{macro} d\tau $$
And since over each blob the potential, which has been smoothened out, stays somewhat constant, I can take it out of the integral and write: $$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{all blobs} \phi_{macro} \iiint \rho_{macro} d\tau$$ which boils down to the previous summation i wrote. Hence, the integral representing the macroscopic work is correct.

THINGS TO KEEP IN MIND:

the macroscopic formula inherently does not contain the self energy terms of each of these blobs. One can only expect this from the microscopic formula.

Now consider this:

**Case 1**

I change the system from one to another, by just moving these blobs around. The self energies of these blobs are the same in both the configurations. In such a situation, the work done in reconfiguring the system would simply be:

$${\frac{1}{2} \iiint_{all space} \rho_{macro} \phi_{macro} d\tau }_{final state} - {\frac{1}{2} \iiint_{all space} \rho_{macro} \phi_{macro} d\tau}_{initial state} $$

**Case 2**

If i change my system at a **fundamental** level, as in, the microscopic structure has changed now. Here, the macroscopic formula would not give us the correct redistribution energy, as the self energies of each of the blobs are different, since the blobs themselves are now different. (Unless I'm terribly wrong on this part, in which case, kindly explain me how)

If you want an example, take a situation where I flatten a system of charges completely, to create a sheet charge distribution. We obviously cannot use this formula here.

If you are gonna tell me it isn't a physical situation so I shouldn't worry about it, think of what happens when a battery does work to charge up a parallel plate capacitor? Blobs of electrons inside a thick (somewhat)'wire suddenly redistributes itself into a thin plate? The work we are calculating using the formula would give us wrong results right? (According to my intuition, i think it'll give wrong results)

(I suppose one could consider the whole system of wires and capacitors as a system, excluding the battery, and assert that the change in the macroscopic work would simply be the change in the energy stored in the macroscopic fields, (derived from Maxwell's laws), but it is still not clear what happens to the self energy terms)

**QUESTIONS**

1. So what happens to the self energies, they must be different, right? In hindsight, I suppose the formula still gives us the correct result, but it's not at all clear to me *why* it would. Or whether it would, at all.
2. Is my physical interpretation of the situation correct? The macroscopic formula, atleast to my interpretation, means this; bringing blobs from infinity. But there could be a more mathematical, less physical formulation of the same, which contains the hidden details that i don't get from my physical picture. Perhaps the averaging procedure could somehow preserve some quantities, like this? Nonetheless, this isn't clear to me, what is exactly happening. If someone could show me that the averaging procedure could bring out these results to clearer light, I would appreciate it.

Comment: for all the length of your post it is not clear what sample of charges you are talking about. You are basically talking about creating a plasma, i.e, an overall neutral sample with charges in motion. http://www.plasmas.org/

Comment: @annav , I am working within the domains of electrostatics. Whatever charges prescribed, they are fixed charges. If i speak about moving or shuffling charges, it is implied I'm doing so in a very slow manner. I don't know why you think I'm talking about plasma, i don't know the first thing about plasma

Comment: What do you mean isn't mainstream physics? Many textbooks treat the work done by a battery to charge a capacitor against electrostatic forces only, so what's the particular issue you are having with my question? FNH Robinson extensively treats the work done against electrostatic forces to reconfigure a system of charges, from the perspective of macroscopic quantities, but leaves out the part where one is able to change the configuration at a level that is more than macroscopic, eg, blobs of electrons travelling inside a wire which distribute themselves onto a thin conducting plate (very thin)

Comment: @annav I think you are missing the essense of my question. I think it's well within the framework of electrostatics to ask about the work done against electrostatic forces to build a system of charges, or to shift from one system to another. It is well established fact that on changing the system only at a macroscopic level, as in moving each of these blobs of charges, we can readily subtract the 2 integrals. But in cases when one fundamentally changes things, like in the case of a capacitor, I am just asking about the validity of the formula, and if valid, how does it come mathematically

Comment: then the reason for closure is that the type of charge and the material has to be defined and your question is too general .

Comment: Electrostatics does not work in the way you imagine. Two like larges will repulse and move away from each other. Two unlike charges will attract and move on to each other. The notion of changing a system of charges in a "fundamental way" can only apply with extra interactions. I have revoked my close choice, and cannot close again. I would choose"
*Needs more focus

This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.+

Comment: @annav The question is basically asking the validity of the formula $(\frac{1}{2} \iiint \rho_{macro} \phi_{macro} d\tau)_{final}-(\frac{1}{2} \iiint \rho_{macro} \phi_{macro} d\tau)_{initial} $ in cases where I microscopically change the configuration; for example; battery working to charge a capacitor. Most textbooks (like griffiths) use this work only, and this bothers me. if I am wrong in the interpretation of the formula, and hence it somehow turns out to be applicable, then id like an answer for that aswell. is it really wrong to ask these two related questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to address some of your concerns with a specific example. You wrote a lot, so I'm not exactly sure this will answer the things you are most concerned about, but I think there are some useful considerations here.

The voltage due to a sphere of uniform charge distribution in its center is $(3/2)kQ/r$, where $k=1/4\pi\epsilon_0$, $Q$ is the total charge, and $r$ is the radius of the sphere. The potential on the outer edge of that sphere is $kQ/r$. They differ by 50%, not a small fraction, no mater how small the sphere is. These will be the "blobs" in my example (with a lowercase $r$).

If you wanted to calculate the energy it would take to assemble such a sphere from point charges taken from infinitely far away, it would not suffice to approximate the potential in the "blob" as constant. If you take the potential in the center as the potential throughout, you would be overestimating the energy by something on the order of 50% (idk probably more like 25%). I think this makes you correct in saying that the macroscopic formula would not correctly capture the energy it would take if you "reshaped the blobs."

And so if the energy it took to assemble your "blobs" was significant compared to the energy it took to put your blobs together, indeed this formula would be wrong (it would incorrectly estimate the energy it took to assemble the blobs):
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\text{blob }i}\phi_{\text{macro}}(x_i)\iiint\rho_{\text{macro}}dV=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\text{blob }i}\phi_{\text{macro}}(x_i)Q_i
$$

However, if you took a trillion such spheres and assembled them into a bigger sphere of radius $R\gg r$, then the potential in the center of that bigger sphere would be approximately $(3/2) kNQ/R$, where $N$ is the number of smaller spheres. Consider a small sphere sitting near the middle of the big sphere.  Since $R\propto N^{1/3}$, the potential it experiences is much bigger than $kQ/r$ (by a factor $\sim N^{2/3}$), **so its self assembly energy is much smaller than the energy it took to move to the center**. This is the sense in which your various forms of this work formula are correct - they are correct if self assembly energies of the blobs are negligible. And furthermore, this example shows that it's reasonably common that *most of the energy* does come from assembling the macroscopic charge distribution, not from making the microscopic charges that are a part of that.

You can also ensure this when you do your Lorentz averaging - make sure that your averaging spheres are big enough to make a continuous function, but small enough that the self-assembly energy of the all the blobs remains negligible.

Otherwise they might also be correct if you only wanted to calculate how much work it took to assemble the bigger charge distribution, assuming the smaller spheres came pre-assembled. This is often the framework in which we calculate the energy it took to assemble a group of point charges. The energy it takes to make a point charge is *infinite*, so only changes in energy are even worth attempting to calculate.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I'm quite convinced, to a good approximation that in any case of reconfiguring a large mass of blobs, (atleast, if the linear dimensions are much large), one can safely say the self energy terms are not significant (and their difference even more so). But it remains to see how things work out, when let's say, a bunch of electrons is moved from a wire onto a thin sheet. What is the analysis method physists use in such a situation, where one of the linear DImension, the thickness of the parallel plate capacitor, is very very small?

Comment: @nickbros123 I think the headline is that this method of lorentz averaging to remove the difficulty of point charges/microscopic structure is valid - so now you can go out and apply it to whatever situation you want. As for the specific question you ask (I don't really see the relation to the original question?), a wire has infinite energy, or rather energy that goes to infinity like $\lambda\log(r/l)=(Q/l) \log(r/l)$ (charge $q$, length $l$, radius $r$). Then the plane diverges like $l\sigma=Q/l$ (charge $q$, square side length $l$). So "infinite" energy is released ($\propto\log(r)$)