# Dielectric (and non-dielectric) Electrostatic Energy - some possible misconceptions and interpretations

Tags: electrostatics, energy, charge, dielectric, self-energy

Suppose one is given with a system of charges, and is tasked to find the work it takes to build it, in a purely electrostatic situation. Microscopically, it is clear the answer is simply:
$$\iiint \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{0} (\vec e \cdot \vec e )d^3t $$
where $e$ is the microscopic electric field. Keep in mind I am ignoring the self energy which is divergent and is position independent.
This works because of the Lorentz force law, $f_{d}= \rho_{micro} \vec e$, being exactly true for point particles. (here $f_{d}$ is the microscopic force density)

Now when one has only access to the average electric field, $E=\langle e \rangle$, I am tempted to average the force density $f_{d}$ over a microscopically large volume $\Delta \Omega$, which gives:

$$\tilde f_{d} = \langle f_{d} \rangle$$
$$\rightarrow \iiint_{\Delta \Omega}(\tilde f_{d}) d^3t=\iiint_{\Delta \Omega}( f_{d}) d^3t$$
where $\Delta \Omega$ is a microscopically large volume.
The force law approximately reads (does not in all cases, but I nonetheless assume it does) :

$$\tilde f_{d}=\rho_{macro}\vec E=-\rho_{macro}\nabla \phi_{macro}$$

Now if I want to infer anything physically from the above formula, my integration volume must be of a significant size, again as mentioned above, more than $\Delta \Omega$.

$$F(r)\cdot dr=-\iiint_{\Delta \Omega} (\rho_{M}(r+t)\nabla\phi_{M}(r+t)\cdot dr)d^3t$$
considering $\infty$ as reference:
$$\rightarrow W=\iiint_{\Delta \Omega} \rho_{M}(r+t)\phi_{M}(r+t)d^3t$$
$$t \in \Delta \Omega$$
this would give me the work it takes to move a microscopically large volume of charge in presence of an external field $E_{macro}$ which produces the potential $\phi_{M}$

## Picture 1

In constructing a given configuration using macroscopic variables, lets bring each of these microscopically large collection of charges, which I'd like to call blobs, from infinity. If the potential, which is averaged, is approximately constant over a surface, we can then consider the integral $$\iiint_{\mathbb{R^3}}\frac{1}{2} \rho_{M} \phi_{M} d^3t$$
$$\rightarrow \sum_{all blobs} \iiint_{\Delta \Omega_{i}}\frac{1}{2} \rho_{M} \phi_{M} d^3t$$
$$\approx \sum_{all blobs} \phi_{{M}_{i}}\iiint_{\Delta \Omega_{i}}\frac{1}{2} \rho_{M} d^3t$$
$$\approx \sum_{all blobs} \frac{1}{2}\phi_{{M}_{i}}\rho_{M} \Delta \Omega$$
which gives us the correct work done to bring all these blobs and construct the system. From here, it is simple to show that the work is $$ W= \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{0} \iiint_{all space} E^2 d^3t$$
But it is clear from this bit of analysis that there is no inclusion of the self energy terms of these individual blobs themselves. In some rudimentary cases, this can be ignored, and can be shown to be negligible in comparison to the interactions between the blobs themselves, especially if the number of these blobs are of the order $10^{20}$ see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/765066/346785

(note: I implicitly have assumed that the potential remains approximately constant over the volume, and ideally it must be for that is one of the goals of the averaging, apart from just killing off high frequency terms)

### Some inferences

We brought the blob from infinity to its stipulated point, and the $\phi_{M}$ we used is due to everything. But we make use of the entire charge $\iiint_{\Delta \Omega} \rho_{M} d^3 t$ in our analysis, so there is no way we have included the self energy term of these blobs themselves in this picture.

## Picture 2

This is slightly more intricate; suppose at a juncture, we have a configuration of charges given by $\rho_{M}(r)$. At the point $r$, we add an infinitesimally small charge, whose volume is nonetheless microscopically large, in order to increase the charge density at $r$ from $\rho_{M}(r)$ to $\rho_M(r)+\delta \rho_M(r)$. In the process, the work done by me, to work against the electric fields produced by $\rho_{M}$ to bring this blob is $$\partial W=\iiint_{\Delta \Omega} \delta \rho_{M} \phi_{M} d^3 t $$ and *if* $\phi_{M}$ and $\rho_{M}$ are constant over $\Delta \Omega$ then I can take it out of the integral and write:
$$\partial{W}= \delta \rho_{M} \phi_{M} \Delta \Omega$$
Notice that a change of resolution from $d^3 t$ to $\Delta \Omega$ has taken place (this isn't necessary)

$$\partial W=\iiint_{\Delta \Omega} \delta \rho_{M} \phi_{M} d^3 t $$
$$\rightarrow \int \partial W=\iiint_{all space} \delta \rho_{M} \phi_{M} d^3 t $$
$$\rightarrow \int \partial W=\iiint_{all space} \epsilon_{0} \nabla \cdot \delta \vec E  \phi_{M} d^3 t $$
(after some vector calculus)
$$\rightarrow \int \partial W=W=\iiint_{all space} \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{0} E^2 d^3 t $$
giving us the same result as picture 1.

### Some inferences

Here, we didn't discretely bring the entire blob from infinity to its stipulated place, but we brought them piece by piece, infinitesimally building the charge density, slowly building the scaffold that finally would give us $\rho_{M}$. In each interval of adding an infinitesimal variation of charge density to every point, and making $\rho \to \rho + \delta \rho$, the potential acting on the next bit of charge that comes to the same point $r$, is now different, and has increased by a 1st order differential for it is after all a function of charge density. And moreover, we, like picture 1, include all the charges in our consideration for $\phi$ , including the potential at $r$, due to $\rho$. therefore, there exists a semblance of self energy, albeit in a very indirect way, for the $\delta \rho $ blob that gets added to the point $r$ does feel a force from the existing charges at $r$, the total of which makes up the final blob at r, $\iiint \rho(r)d^3 t$

## The Usual analysis done for Dielectrics

Same as picture 2, but instead of bringing $\delta \rho_{M}$, you bring $\delta \rho_{free}$, and all of the analysis copies here, except the final result (apply gauss law for dielectrics and some vector calc):

$$W=\frac{1}{2}\int \iiint_{All space} \delta D \cdot E d^3 t $$
for linear dielectrics:
$$W=\frac{1}{2}\iiint_{All space} D \cdot E d^3 t $$

## What has changed? Conclusions(?)

We can conclude that in all 3 pictures, the potential is due to the $\rho$ that exists due to *all* charges, but picture 1 does not contain any self energy terms whatsoever, of the blobs themselves. Only the interaction energy terms.

Picture 2, from my understanding, *does* contain some sort of an approximate self energy term which is washed out due to the averaging, yet exists. I conclude that we get the same result nonetheless at least for non dielectrics as these self energy terms come to be negligible. Kindly correct me on this point if I am wrong.

What is interesting is that we are **not** getting the same result in the case of dielectrics. Why is this the case? what is even more peculiar is the difference term corresponds to $\frac{1}{2}\iiint \vec P \cdot \vec E d^3 t$ which has *something* to do with the polarisation, but nothing is clear. I might be speculating, but this extra term may be some approximate yet more accurate self energy term of the blobs themselves? I mean what else could it be?

Why is this extra term coming, when clearly the analysis I applied in picture 2 and picture 3 are very similar. What difference does it make if I bring all the charges whatever, not differentiating the bound and the free, or if I bring the free and let the bound charge do its thing? After all, given a final configuration and given that all the internal forces are conservative and centre to centre, the work done by the internal forces are frame and path independent.

In all the cases I am using the potential due to the averaged out $\rho$, so obviously I am not capturing any information about the microscopic nature of the situation, at least not directly.

It would be nice if someone explained to me in detail where the extra term is coming from in the difference between picture 2 and the dielectric case, (obviously, it would be optimal if one could show it without plugging it in secretly from the back) and *if* I have any misconceptions about the situation(s), please correct it.